# Dynamic dropdowns - for sales contact management exercise

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to figure out a method in Google spreadsheets where I would be able to display information of contacts after I have selected 2 more criterias before.

So imagine it this way:

You see a dropdown menu in a cell - with the names of account owners - if you select an owner in the next column the dropdown menu would contain only the accounts the account owner has.
Once you select an account in the next column the dropdown menu would contain all the contacts that belongs to that account.
If you select a contact the rest of the columns would display information related to that contact (like job title, email, phone etc.)

So far this is doable with just a simple filter, right?
Here comes the difficulty.

We have one row of data now right?

What I would like to be able to do is start the same process in the next row (this is why it needs to be dropdown and not a filter). 
Selecting the account owner (in the first column in that row) then account name then contact name and the rest of the columns for that row would be filled with the contact information.
So after doing the dropdowns on the second row we would end up with something like: http://prntscr.com/alkhvf

I've tried to look at solutions like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkpBms7DKgo
Which seems to work with pre-set data, and it does not account for information that is not in a dropdown.

So right now I am pretty clueless how (if) this is doable.
Anyone put together something like this? Can you help me with this dilemma?

All replies are appreciated!

Comment: You can have dropdowns taking values from certain range (in the same row, but probably on another sheet out of the view), where the content of that range is determined by a formula based on the previous dropdown. Then after all the dropdowns, do either filter or query fetching the row that matches dropdown values.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This site isn't' a forum. Instead of replies, it has questions, answers and comments :).

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to work with pre-set data"? What criteria options did you tried?